# Accessing UINavigationItem with Good Design Principles

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, oop, uinavigationitem

I am working on an iOS app where we have a class called a FlowController that manages the flow of a group of`UIViewControllers`.

So our basic structure is we create an instance of a FlowController which creates a`UINavigationController` and then creates child view controllers to push onto the navigation controller as the user interacts with the view controller's views.

If a user interacts with a view related to flow, the view controller delegates that action up to the flow controller which then manages pushing a new view controller onto the navigation stack.

The purpose of this was to keep flow code outside of the view controller to make our view controllers more modular.

As we developed this concept and as our designer started adding more`UIBarButtonItems` in our app, I realized I could add`UIBarButtonItems` to the`UIViewController's` -navigationItem property from within the FlowController with the target being the FlowController and selector being a selector in the flow controller.

Example:

```
//Code in FlowController

-(void) startFlow{
    UIViewController* firstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self nextBarButtonItem];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}

-(UIBarButtonItem*) nextBarButtonItem{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" target:self selector:@selector(next:)];
}

-(void) next:(id) sender{
    UIViewController* secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController: secondViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

This way I was thinking I was being efficient with code because we have several screens that use the same view controller but have different bar button items in the navigation bar.

When I talked to one of my coworkers about this however he said this was violating design principles because I was accessing "view" code from outside of a view controller.

Specifically I was creating`UIBarButtonItems` in our FlowController. He told me we should never access a`UIViewController's` -`navigationItem`property from outside of anything other than a`UIViewController` subclass and that what I was doing was breaking the Object Oriented design principle of encapsulation.

He suggested I should create methods on a`UIViewController` that take a target and selector that add`UIBarButtonItems` to the view controller's -`navigationItem`internally. Then call that method within the FlowController.

Example:

```
//Code in UIViewController

-(void) addRightBarButtonItemWithTitle:(NSString*) title target:(id) target selector:(SEL) selector{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:title target:target selector:selector];
}

//Code in FlowController

-(void) startFlow{
    UIViewController* firstViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [firstViewController addRightBarButtonItemWithTitle:@"Next" target:self selector:@selector(next:)];

   [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

My initial instinct is to disagree with that however because the FlowController is in the scope of the "Controller" portion of our MVC app and a controller should be allowed to access views. Additionally if I do as my coworker suggests I would have to add a

`-addRightBarbuttonItemWithTitle:target:selector`

method on each view controller I have or create a subclass that each view controller would have to inherit from.

This seems like a lot of overhead and unneeded dependency for the idea of "encapsulating" and also restrictively wrapping the interface to the navigationItem (as now I can only have a -`rightBarButtonItem`with text; no image or custom views.

So finally getting to my question: is it bad Object Oriented programming to access a`UIViewController's` -`navigationItem`property from outside of a`UIViewController` subclass? And if so, why does Apple make it publicly available? (I know the concept of protected does't really exist in Objective C but it does in Swift where it is still publicly available.)

Comment: don't write question like story.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, whether the flow controller should populate `navigationItem`s or not depends on how you look at it:

- If the (step) view controller's navigation items are dependent / linked / have some sort of relationships with the content of view controller, then they should be decided by the view controller. This further breaks down into 2 cases:

  - If the step view controller was designed as an independent component, which is not aware of the flow, and could live without the flow, then it should provide methods to configure the nagivation items, and hooks (delegates) to assign handler to the navigation items' events. By "configure" it means exactly what your coworker suggested.
  - If the step view controller is part of the flow, and is aware of its owner flow controller, it can just call the flow controller's method directly (e.g. `nextStep`, `previousStep`).
- If the (step) view controller's navigation items are completely independent of the view controller's content -- in other words, the step view controller has the capability to have some navigation items, but it doesn't care about its nav items -- then the flow controller can modify those nav items directly. This is what you did initially.

In both Obj C and Swift, `navigationItems` are public, and often methods/properties migrated from Obj C becomes public in Swift. Neither Swift and Obj C has the concept of "protected" and it seems Apple doesn't care ([inheritance, or not?](http://www.objc.io/issue-13/subclassing.html)).